# Repartitioning Changing Row Order of Dataframe in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, partition, pyspark

I want to understand what is happening to my dataframe after I apply the .repartition function. If my original dataframe is:

```
+--------+------+--------------+-------+-----+
|integers|floats|integer_arrays|letters|nulls|
+--------+------+--------------+-------+-----+
|       1|  -1.0|        [1, 2]|      a|    1|
|       2|   0.5|     [3, 4, 5]|      b| null|
|       3|   2.7|  [6, 7, 8, 9]|      c|    2|
+--------+------+--------------+-------+-----+
```

And I run:

```
df.repartition(10).show()
```

The resulting dataframe has the rows in a different order:

```
+--------+------+--------------+-------+-----+
|integers|floats|integer_arrays|letters|nulls|
+--------+------+--------------+-------+-----+
|       3|   2.7|  [6, 7, 8, 9]|      c|    2|
|       2|   0.5|     [3, 4, 5]|      b| null|
|       1|  -1.0|        [1, 2]|      a|    1|
+--------+------+--------------+-------+-----+
```

Why does the order of the rows change?

What is actually happening to a dataframe with 3 rows that gets split into 10 partitions?

Can I see the partitions that it has assigned?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial DataFrame has its rows distributed over different partitions. When you call `show` a subset of rows is being taken from the partitions and passed to the driver, which will then display them in a tabular format.

To see the partitions to which your rows are assigned, use the pyspark sql function `spark_partition_id()`:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import spark_partition_id
>>> df0 = spark.range(3)
>>> df1 = df0.withColumn("partition_id_before", spark_partition_id())
>>> df1.show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|partition_id_before|
+---+-------------------+
|  0|                  1|
|  1|                  2|
|  2|                  3|
+---+-------------------+
```

Now, when you ask to reshuffle, Spark will compute a hash value of each row and based on that and the default number of partitions used in a shuffle operation, move each row to a (possibly different) partition, as you can see below:

```
>>> df2 = df1.repartition(10).withColumn("partition_id_after", spark_partition_id())
>>> df2.show()
+---+-------------------+------------------+
| id|partition_id_before|partition_id_after|
+---+-------------------+------------------+
|  2|                  3|                 5|
|  0|                  1|                 6|
|  1|                  2|                 9|
+---+-------------------+------------------+
```

In general, as Spark is a framework for distributed processing, my suggestion is not to rely on (perceived) positional order of rows and consider the contents of a DataFrame as a *set* (a collection lacking order, like in group theory) of rows. Functions like `orderBy` usually only serve display purposes, to get e.g. the top N results from something and then order is important. In the majority of operations, ignore order though.